# Install pygobject without root permissions

Tags: path, installation, glib, pygobject

I am trying to install pygobject-2.11.3 without root permissions. I downloaded the source, and when running ./configure --prefix=/home/my_username/local i get :

> checking for GLIB - version >= 2.8.0... no
>   *** Could not run GLIB test program, checking why...**
>    The test program failed to compile or link. See the file config.log for the
>   ** exact error that occured. This usually means GLIB is incorrectly installed. 
>   configure: error: maybe you want the pygobject-2-4 branch?

So i installed glib-2.8.6 the same way (./configure --prefix=/home/my_username/local && make && make install)
No error message for glib.

After trying to reinstall pyobject i get the same error.

When looking in the logs i see : glib.h : no such file or directory

So it seems the ./configure script of pyobject doesnt find glib.h which is in /home/my_username/local/include

/home/my_username/local is the first element of my $PATH

uname -a :
Linux u205 2.6.9-42.ELsmp #1 SMP Wed Jul 12 23:32:02 EDT 2006 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

The script configure uses pkg-config and given you installed a library in a non-canonical directory, you need to set the variable `PKG_CONFIG_PATH`.

In your specific case, it should be:

```
$ export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/home/my_username/local/lib/pkgconfig
```

In order to test it, you can try:

```
$ pkg-config --modversion glib-2.0
```

Later you can re-run the script configure.  In the future, you might want to take a look to [jhbuild](https://live.gnome.org/Jhbuild).

Comment: I was installing in a different directory but had the same problem as Victor. After seting PKG_CONFIG_PATH pkg-config returns glibs version, but the same error is still reported when using ./configure. Any further advise?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add to LD_LIBRARY_PATH the path to the installed GLIB.

Regards,
Manuel

Answer (score -1):

You need to set the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable, e.g.

```
env PYTHONPATH=/home/my_username/local/lib/python/ <command>
```

If you are using Bash, put this in your bashrc:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/home/my_username/local/lib/python/
```

The semantics are very much the same as for `PATH`, apart from that `PYTHONPATH` it is being used by Python to look for modules, while `PATH` is used by the shell to look for commands. Therefore you can have multiple directories:

```
export PYTHONPATH = "/code/proj_A/lib/python/:/code/proj_B/lib/python/"
```

See [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path) for more information.

Comment: PYTHONPATH is for running python scripts.  PyGObject is a library written in C to add GObject Introspection support to Python.